# Error when creating external table in Redshift Spectrum with dbt: cross-database reference not supported

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I want to create an external table in Redshift Spectrum from CSV files. When I try doing so with dbt, I get a strange error. But when I manually remove some double quotes from the SQL generated by dbt and run it directly, I get no such error.

First I run this in Redshift Query Editor v2 on default database `dev` in my cluster:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA example_schema
FROM DATA CATALOG
DATABASE 'example_db'
REGION 'us-east-1'
IAM_ROLE 'iam_role'
CREATE EXTERNAL DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS
;
```

Database `dev` now has an external schema named `example_schema` (and Glue catalog registers `example_db`).

I then upload `example_file.csv` to the S3 bucket `s3://example_bucket`. The file looks like this:

```
col1,col2
1,a,
2,b,
3,c
```

Then I run `dbt run-operation stage_external_sources` in my local dbt project and get this output with an error:

```
21:03:03  Running with dbt=1.0.1
21:03:03  [WARNING]: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.
There are 1 unused configuration paths:
- models.example_project.example_models

21:03:03  1 of 1 START external source example_schema.example_table
21:03:03  1 of 1 (1) drop table if exists "example_db"."example_schema"."example_table" cascade
21:03:04  Encountered an error while running operation: Database Error
  cross-database reference to database "example_db" is not supported
```

I try running the generated SQL in Query Editor:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "example_db"."example_schema"."example_table" CASCADE
```

and get the same error message:

```
ERROR: cross-database reference to database "example_db" is not supported
```

But when I run *this* SQL in Query Editor, it works:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "example_db.example_schema.example_table" CASCADE
```

Note that I just removed some quotes.

**What's going on here? Is this a bug in `dbt-core`, `dbt-redshift`, or `dbt_external_tables`--or just a mistake on my part?**

To confirm, I can successfully create the external table by running this in Query Editor:

```sql
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS example_schema
DROP EXTERNAL DATABASE
CASCADE
;
CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA example_schema
FROM DATA CATALOG
DATABASE 'example_db'
REGION 'us-east-1'
IAM_ROLE 'iam_role'
CREATE EXTERNAL DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS
;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE example_schema.example_table (
  col1 SMALLINT,
  col2 CHAR(1)
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://example_bucket'
TABLE PROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
;
```

---

### dbt config files

`models/example/schema.yml` (modeled after [this example](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables/blob/0.8.0/sample_sources/redshift.yml):

```yaml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: example_source
    database: dev
    schema: example_schema
    loader: S3
    tables:
      - name: example_table
        external:
          location: 's3://example_bucket'
          row_format: >
            serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
            with serdeproperties (
              'strip.outer.array'='false'
            )
          columns:
            - name: col1
              data_type: smallint
            - name: col2
              data_type: char(1)
```

`dbt_project.yml`:

```yaml
name: 'example_project'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

profile: 'example_profile'

model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"
clean-targets:
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"

models:
  example_project:
    example:
      +materialized: view
```

`packages.yml`:

```yaml
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_external_tables
    version: 0.8.0
```